# CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 3

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sql, cursor

Estoy intentando hacer una consulta con sqlite en android studio, pero cuando intento obtener los valores del cursor para hacer una lista con los resultados de la consulta me vota esa excepción, pero en ocaciones si realiza bien la función, 
hace la consulta y me muestra la lista con los resultados, pero en otras me sale ese  error y no veo por que.

```
                   lista_busqueda.clear();
                    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        do {
                            lista_busqueda.add(new ListaBusquedaTELCEL(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FormaBaseTELCEL.ID)),
                                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FormaBaseTELCEL.TELEFONO)),
                                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FormaBaseTELCEL.NOMBRE1)),
                                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FormaBaseTELCEL.NOMBRE2))));
                        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                    }
                    cursor.close();
```

Este es la parte del codigo en la que me marca el error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probe haciendo esto, y me ha resultado ya no me da esa exeption.

```
lista_busqueda.clear();
                if(cursor.getCount > 0 && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        lista_busqueda.add(new ListaBusquedaTELCEL(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FormaBaseTELCEL.ID)),
                                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FormaBaseTELCEL.TELEFONO)),
                                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FormaBaseTELCEL.NOMBRE1)),
                                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FormaBaseTELCEL.NOMBRE2))));
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
                cursor.close();
```